# I can't set a custom Master page for all the sub site ?

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, custom-masterpage, html5

I applied a custom master page for my site,I need to apply the same for various sub site without setting page(system page),But its not working fine.I applied my custom master page to system page also then all the sub sites applying my master page other wise it's not working. I tried checking this check box  Reset all sub sites to inherit this site master page setting.Then also its not inheriting.

Comment: Kindly check that your subsite is inheriting the master page from parent site.

Comment: ya  that's a issues,I checked that check box of Reset all sub sites to inherit this site master page setting,But its automatically unchecked after the page load.@ Hardik